# Set BorderPane components size

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to set the size of the Center, Top, Left, Right and Bottom components of a BorderPane.

[image]

So far I found this:

```
BorderPane() mainpane = new BorderPane();
mainPane.getBottom().prefWidth(sizeX);
```

For example how I can you get the size of a Left side of a BorderPane and set the size?

Answer (score 3):

the "Left" of a BorderPane is whatever you set it to and it's size is whatever you set it to.

example:

```
BorderPane mainpane = new BorderPane();
StackPane left = new StackPane();
left.setPrefWidth(100);
mainPane.setLeft(left);
```